# HAML ActionView::Template::Error SyntaxError: stdin missing indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm really stuck.  I had some code which used to work, but does not on my new branch.

I am getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:79:1: missing indentation):
    1: !!! html
    2: %html
    3:   %head
    4:     %link{rel: 'shortcut icon', href: image_path('analyst-console-favicon.ico')}
    5: 
    6:   %body
```

My layout file has the following:

```
!!! html
%html
  %head
    %link{rel: 'shortcut icon', href: image_path('analyst-console-favicon.ico')}

  %body
```

I did a hexdump and verified that the indentation uses spaces.

If I delete the `%link` line, then it returns the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I don't even know what to check might be wrong.

Comment: The error doesn't seems to be in layout but the template being render by the action just called. Check all the templates participate serving the reuqest.

Comment: I deleted all the code in my view file so it is now blank.  I have a layout specific to that control which did a `render template:` so I copied the code for the layout above to replace the `render` command.  I still get the same error.

Comment: I got a downvote for the question, but I might not delete it.  Thing is the error message specifically identifies the template which was misleading.  I was stuck.  I could not find information on the internet related to this error message, so I hope to leave this hint to other people who have this problem.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You don't delete a question because it got a downvote or a vote to close, you fix the question. Your question isn't repeatable; You're asking us to help debug, but we can't run the code and duplicate a problem, and that's off-topic. And, from your "answer", which it isn't, you had a syntax error, which again is off-topic.

Comment: @theTinMan When I searched the web for "stdin missing indentation" there was no results.  There ought to be something to point people in the right direction somewhere, so if nowhere else, then this article.  That a completely different file than the file in the error message was the cause is a hint I wish someone had provided to me.  If there was more explanation for this error message, I would agree to deleting this question.

Comment: Reading "How to Ask", "Stack Overflow question checklist", I checked off every item in the checklists.  For "MCVE", I did the best I could to provide the information to the minimal but complete explanation of what was happening.  I removed all the code in the file referenced in the error message until I found one line which including or excluding toggled whether there was an error.  If I had had the information to reproduce it, I would have solved it.  A search of the error message on a web search engine, this is the only article about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had comments in a coffee script file which were indented.  When I removed the indentation and had the comments flush with the left column of the file it works.  It fully works.

It seems bizarre that having the shortcut icon link toggles whether the indents in the coffee script break the code or not.